# Is it possible to create a master template file in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, office365

Is it possible in Excel to create a single master template file?

My goal would bet to make a change in the master file and all of the files that were based off this template would be updated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did something like this once : had a template opened by a macro (before vba) first step after opening was to check its own version number against the number on the server - if it was older then it would download the new file replacing itself... Then it would check and download the relevant data, but it was always starting blank, which may not fit the way you need to work.